# Blue Screen "session3_initialization_failed" error on Windows XP after loading

Tags: windows, bsod

I was using my Acer netbook, then it rebooted and now I'm getting this blue screen when I try to get into Windows XP. It takes a lot of time to load and then this blue screen of death error comes.

I tried to get in under safe mode but no success.

Could be some virus or missing some file or hardware problem?

Answer (score 1):

A critical windows system file may be corrupted or missing, [a repair Install of XP](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/516-repairing-windows-xp-using-cd-installation) would solve that issue.